# Debian 8 UEFI support

Tags: debian, uefi, debian-installer

I am trying to install Debian Jessie on my new laptop. I downloaded the amd64 Live CD, but the UEFI doesn't recognize my Debian DVD ROM.

I disabled the secure UEFI option, but it didn't work, UEFI doesn't show CD/DVD boot option. I attempted to boot with an Ubuntu Live CD and it works fine.

I thought that Debian supported UEFI boot.

Any ideas?

Note: My laptop is a Dell Inspiron 15 5000 Series with Windows 8.1.

Comment: How does it 'not work'? Please provide error messages, or explain the failure mode in more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yesterday I installed Debian on a recent Asus Pxx model using the netinstall-iso using a usb-stick and I was able to finish the install without any problems or warnings.
  - secure boot MUST be disabled and this is often only possible cq visible upon setting a bios-password.
Have you tried writing the iso to a stick ?

Comment: thanks for reply your experience. I will try using an usb to install Debian.